# Can I say "Then came they/them"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

As far as I know, this way of arranging a sentence is not present in common English, at least this particular example.

> Then came **they/them**.

Are both sentences correct, considering that we are in a rather literary context? I wanted to give this statement a poetic/dramatic tone, so this turning of sentence elements came to my mind, instead of the flat "Then they came."

Comment: This particular "poetic inversion" isn't common with ***pronouns***, but it's perfectly natural in many contexts with ***proper nouns***. Especially with certain additional prepositions - for example, *I waited two hours for the bus. Then **along came three** buses at once* (as opposed to *then three buses came along [all] at once* - Subject+Verb rather than Verb+Subject).

Answer (score 2):

That style of English immediately reminds me of JRR Tolkein, but he himself was harking back to earlier times - I believe it was outmoded usage even then.

So, if this is in a literary or poetic context, you will probably be fine - it's perfectly understandable to a native speaker.

Comment: Thanks. I guess your answer refers to both cases, ie "they" and "them"?

Comment: Actually, no, 'them' would be a bit too unusual, in my opinion.

Comment: _Them_ is object case and cannot be used in this context. We wouldn't say _Them came_.